# Comparing Results From Two Different Queries Based on Common Field

Tags: sql-server

Ok, so I just started working with SQL so please be easy on me if there's a super easy solution that I just don't know. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. I have two queries that give me results, one being

```
EXEC ('SELECT  ID ,        
  Type,        
  Date                
  FROM DB2T.BBT') AT DB2
```

and the other being

```
select 
    ca.value('(/CA[@name=''ID'']/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') as ID,
    ca.value('(/CA[@name=''Type'']/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Type,
    ca.value('(/CA[@name=''Date'']/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Date,
from log
```

This is just how I extract the relevant data from the places I need. I end up with two different queries with two different table outputs, each row containing an ID, Type, and Date.

I need to combine these two queries so I can compare the two tables. I need to see, depending on matching IDs from the two queries, if the values for Type and Date are equal. I only want to output IDs that have differing values and then output the differing values with it.

So I have two problems I guess, one being combining the two queries and then doing the comparing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This query will combine the resultsets into one, then group by the ID, Type, and Date columns and pull back which ones don't have two rows (should have one from DB2 and one from SQL). It doesn't tell you exactly what is different but should be pretty easy to tell with that few columns.

```
SELECT
    MIN(System) AS System,
    ID,
    Type,
    Date
FROM (
    select 
        'SQL',
        ca.value('(/CA[@name=''ID'']/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') as ID,
        ca.value('(/CA[@name=''Type'']/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Type,
        ca.value('(/CA[@name=''Date'']/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Date,
    from log

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'DB2', * FROM OPENQUERY([DB2], ''SELECT  ID, Type, Date FROM DB2T.BBT'')
) compare
GROUP BY ID, Type, Date
HAVING COUNT(*) <> 2
ORDER BY ID, Type, Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, break it down into 2 queries.  The first one is qry1, the second is qry2.  You want to use an inner join, because you only want values where Type and Date are equal.  Then, you use a WHERE clause to give you only the records where ID doesn't match.

You may have to put ID in brackets, I can't remember off the top of my head if that's a reserved word or not.  I know both Date and Type are reserved words, and that's why I put them in brackets.

```
SELECT
  qry1.ID as ID1,
  qry1.[Type] as Type1,
  qry1.[Date] as Date1,
  qry2.ID as ID2,
  qry2.[Type] as Type2,
  qry2.[Date] as Date2
FROM
  (SELECT ID, Type, Date                
  FROM DB2T.BBT) as qry1,
INNER JOIN
  (select 
    ca.value('(/CA[@name=''ID'']/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)') as ID,
    ca.value('(/CA[@name=''Type'']/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Type,
    ca.value('(/CA[@name=''Date'']/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as Date,
    from log) as qry2
  ON qry1.[Type] = qry2.[Type]
  AND qry1.[Date] = qry2.[Date]
WHERE qry1.ID <> qry2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

What about comparing computed columns that are hashes of the concatenated column values? Something like this:

```
declare @t1 table (id int, type varchar(max), dt date, hash_bytes as HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(type AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(dt AS NVARCHAR(MAX))))
declare @t2 table (id int, type varchar(max), dt date, hash_bytes as HASHBYTES('SHA1', CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(type AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(dt AS NVARCHAR(MAX))))

insert into @t1 values 
(1, 'val1', getdate()),        -- no match in @t2 
(2, 'val2', getdate() + 1),
(3, 'val3', getdate() + 2),
(4, 'val4', getdate() + 3),
(5, 'val5', getdate() + 4)

insert into @t2 values 
(2, 'val2', getdate() + 1),    -- same
(3, 'val300', getdate() + 2),  -- different type
(4, 'val4', getdate() + 300),  -- different date
(5, 'val500', getdate() + 400),-- different type & date
(6, 'val6', getdate() + 5)     -- no match in @t1

select * 
from @t1 t1
full join @t2 t2 on t1.hash_bytes = t2.hash_bytes

id      type    dt          hash_bytes                                  id      type    dt          hash_bytes
1       val1    2018-07-27  0xF53D672F572DC49D15AE2ECD2F3225624073FEB8  NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
2       val2    2018-07-28  0x8840035CC198447CB1F9D85E97A57F2B08ADB39E  2       val2    2018-07-28  0x8840035CC198447CB1F9D85E97A57F2B08ADB39E
3       val3    2018-07-29  0x372E6A3B48C3C96C2456A514CD9D35CAC4EEEACE  NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
4       val4    2018-07-30  0xE91A2E58D2964BB3BE6BDD1C1ECA3628E956484D  NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
5       val5    2018-07-31  0xB289831856A15334BE60EC4F78502052B15EE4CD  NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL                                        3       val300  2018-07-29  0x2007D7205352EE65013DC21E527780E1FED763D8
NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL                                        4       val4    2019-05-23  0x60CC2C7B3902204E82F137401446EB974EC83C3B
NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL                                        5       val500  2019-08-31  0xFFF8FD045B306B3F1663FC4903CE859A6C9577FB
NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL                                        6       val6    2018-08-01  0x72407548472D00C87E6DDF42A05E0B1B687AACBA
```